# 500 Internal Server Error While Reports in Acumatica

Tags: report, acumatica

The cash summary by branch report is customized report and we can run earlier and the issue is currently happened.
Faced that the issue that is the 500 Internal Server Error when we run the report.
But We have no this server error when run for each month period (Eg- From Date to(11/1/2022), To Date(11/16/2022)) and can't run by year(Eg- From Date(1/1/2018), To Date(11/16/20220). Why is this the case and how to solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSbPm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJPxX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxHzj.png)

We have no this server error when run for each month period (Eg- From Date to(11/1/2022), To Date(11/16/2022)) and can't run by year(Eg- From Date(1/1/2018), To Date(11/16/20220).

Please help to check and let me know any concern

Answer (score 0):

When building the new report, I would set a default values that work, and then be able to use the Preview function. It will execute the report using the default values only during preview.

You can then use that to troubleshoot - start with the base report that works with that range that crashes on the custom report, and then slowly add your changes. You would then find out what change causes the 500 internal server error.

If you have access to the server, you can try using failed request tracing to get additional information on the errors that are not being sent to the web client. Here is a link on how to troubleshoot failed requests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis?source=recommendations